# How can i remove vertical line from UITextView and typed text from left side in DALinedTextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nstextcontainer

I'm using `DALinedTextView` for lined `UITextView`. I want to remove red vertical line and type text from left side. How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Comment` the `[appearance setVerticalLineColor:DEFAULT_VERTICAL_COLOR];` in `initialize` method of `DALinedTextView` and if you don’t want to comment just change the color of `#define DEFAULT_VERTICAL_COLOR`  to    `[UIColor clearColor]` or any other color.
After this in your `viewController` `viewDidLoad` method change `textContainerInset` like--

```
self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(18.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 10.0f);
```

you can change cursor position according your value.

Comment: thanks dev.rk its work for me changing edge insets.. and my red line removed now by using this approach Comment the [appearance setVerticalLineColor:DEFAULT_VERTICAL_COLOR];

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if your problem solved. So that others can take benefit of it.